# Batch - How to detect if a game server is running on a distant machine

Tags: batch-file, server, synchronization, ip, host

My friends and I play Unturned and everyday someone else hosts the server.
I would like to make a batch file that checks if the server is already running on someone else's PC.
We sync our server files using Dropbox. This means files could get corrupted if multiple people started the server at the same time.

Program structure:

```
@echo off
// Check if the server is already hosted elsewhere
if already_hosted
     echo Server is already hosted on {IP}.
else
     start server.exe
```

Comment: on what port the server is listening?Does your friends has static IP addresses?

Comment: Port: 27015, but I need only idea, maybe I will change the port, we have static IPs, we are using hamachi.

Comment: check portqry - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17148  . No reliable native way on windows to check if port is open and listening.

Comment: ok, thx for your help, but i need something automated.

Comment: portqry is a command line tool.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `netstat -na |findstr ":27015.*LISTEN"` and if the errorlevel is 0 that means it's running, if it's not 0 it means it's not running. You don't need any external programs that don't come with Windows, not even CLI ones like portqry.

```
netstat -na |findstr ":27015.*LISTEN"
if errorlevel 1 start server.exe
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this can detect server running on my friends PC.

Comment: You're right, I didn't read the question carefully. Sorry about that. Then I agree with the guy that said portqry should work.  :)